# Scheduled Reminder are Blank

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Civi 5.14 on WordPress 5.2.3

A large chunk of our membership scheduled renewal reminders are arriving to the member's inbox completely blank. It is apparently not all of them, as I ran a test membership and I received my reminder email with no problems, but more than 500 of our members have received blank scheduled reminder emails this year and their memberships are now expired as a result to this.
This problem makes no sense to me and I do not know where to look for a solution. 
Has anyone else experienced this?  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Is this a non-english site? There's some older references that suggest that preferred_mail_format might end up null for some contacts, e.g. at this link there's a SQL statement near the bottom that might fix it if that's the problem: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18157

Comment: It is an English site and we can send all emails from civi to user with no issues.  The issue is only with Automatic scheduled reminders.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using both the HTML and plain text formats? Some email clients or user preference will pick the plain text version and if you don't have the content there, it will be blank for these people.

Comment: I just using HTML format, but more than 500 people in 2019 blocking HTML doesn't sound right to me.  Most of them are using popular accounts like gmail and hotmail.

Comment: Plus when we view the activity log in Civi it shows the message details for these people are blank.  So it has nothing to do with their email client

Comment: So you are not creating *both* an HTML version and a plain text version? If I were receiving repeated e-mails with no content, I might block those too. Have all these people 'opted in' to receiving your e-mails, or are some blocking because they think they are being spammed? What percentage is 500 of all the e-mail addresses on your list?

Comment: Nothing is being blocked.  The CiviReports clearly show a blank email going out.  But thank you for tryin g